# Taylor series - bound $R_n(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm given that $$R_n(x)=\frac{1}{(n-1!)}\int_{0}^x (x-t)^{n-1} f^{(n)}(t) \ dt $$

I am asked to show that if $f$ has continuous $n$'th derivative then $$|R_n(x)| \leq \frac{|x|^n}{n!}\sup|f^{(n)}(t)|$$

Clearly $$|R_n(x)| \leq \frac{1}{(n-1!)}\int_{0}^x (x-t)^{n-1} |f^{(n)}(t)| \ dt$$

But I'm not sure where to go from here.

The solution to this problem says that it should be $$R_n(x) \leq \frac{1}{(n-1!)}\int_{0}^x (x-t)^{n-1} |f^{(n)}(t)| \ dt \leq R_n(x) \leq \sup|f^{(n)}(t)|\frac{1}{(n-1!)}\int_{0}^x (x-t)^{n-1}  \ dt$$ 
I don't understand this though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From  $$R_n(x)=\frac{1}{(n-1!)}\int_{0}^x (x-t)^{n-1} f^{(n)}(t) \ dt $$ if $f^{(n)}(\cdot)$ is **continuous** in a neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ then we have
$$
\sup_{t \in V}|f^{(n)}(t)|=M<\infty
$$ giving

> $$
> \left|R_n(x)\right| \leq \frac{M}{(n-1!)}\left|\int_{0}^x (x-t)^{n-1}  \ dt\right|=M\times\frac{|x|^n}{n!}
> $$

as announced, where we have used $$\displaystyle \int_{0}^x (x-t)^{n-1}  \ dt=\int_{0}^x u^{n-1}  \ du =\frac{x^n}n, \quad (u=x-t). $$